# Reactjs: Dialog open is not working on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to open and close a dialog on a button click from another page/component.
But it is not working on clicking the button.

Any sugegstion what I am missing and doing wrong here with handeling modal.

Thanks in advance.

//TestComponent

```
class TestConnectDialog extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const {isOpen, onOk} = this.props;
  
      return (
        <Dialog
            isopen={this.props.isopen}
            onClose={this.props.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                 Test
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions className="dialog-action">
                <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose} className="primary-button">
                Ok
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      ); 

    }
};

export default TestConnectDialog;
```

// Home page

```
import TestConnectDialog from './TestConnectDialog';
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isOpen: false 
        };
        this.handleTestConnectClick = this.handleTestConnectClick.bind(this);
        //this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
    }

    handleTestConnectClick= () =>{
        this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    }
    render() {
      const {isOpen, onOk} = this.props;
  
      return (
        <div className="section">
            <Button  className="connect-test-button"
              onClick={this.handleTestConnectClick}>
              Test
            </Button>
            <TestConnectDialog isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
        </div>
      ); 

    }
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: You called the prop "isOpen", but then you're using `isopen={this.prop.isopen}` (all lowercase) in the component, could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prop name is spelled incorrectly, it should be `this.props.isOpen` also a quick little tip, it is possible to use just one function for opening/closing the modal.

Something like this will work:

```
handleTestConnectClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
    }));
}
```

here we use our previous state and with the `! operator` we switch from true to false and vice versa

Update 2.0:
After taking a closer look at the [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/), I noticed that your dialog prop for setting the modal visibility is wrong. It should be `open` instead of `isOpen`.

```
import TestConnectDialog from './TestConnectDialog';
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
    //this.handleTestConnectClick = this.handleTestConnectClick.bind(this);
    //this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
    // when using arrow functions you don't need to bind the this keyword
  }

  handleTestConnectClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="section">
        <Button className="connect-test-button"
          // onClick={this.handleTestConnectClick}>
          // change the onClick to the one below
          onClick={ () => this.handleTestConnectClick() }
          Test
         </Button>
        <TestConnectDialog isOpen={this.state.isOpen} handleTestConnectClick={this.handleTestConnectClick}/>
      </div>
    );

  }
};

export default HomePage;
```

In `TestConnectDialog` component:

```
 class TestConnectDialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog
          open={this.props.isOpen}
          onClose={this.props.handleTestConnectClick}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          >
          <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
               Test
              </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions className="dialog-action">
              <Button onClick={this.props.handleTestConnectClick} className="primary-button">
              Ok
              </Button>
          </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    ); 

  }
};

export default TestConnectDialog;
```

Comment: Be sure to pass this function over as a prop to your <TestConnectDialog />, I can update my answer to show you if you can't get it working

Comment: Could you mind if you provide me a sample code.. Might be helpful.

Comment: is this handleTestConnectClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
    );
  } properyly closed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221201/discussion-between-tammy-and-dax).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the props  `<TestConnectDialog isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />` but trying to read it with `isopen={this.props.isopen}`.
Change your code to this: `isopen={this.props.isOpen}`

Comment: Can you create a sandbox? Here everything seems correct! @Tammy

Answer (score 0):

Update TestComponent component as given

```
class TestConnectDialog extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const {isOpen, onOk} = this.props;
  
      return (
        <Dialog
            isopen={isOpen}
            onClose={this.props.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                 Test
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions className="dialog-action">
                <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose} className="primary-button">
                Ok
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      ); 

    }
};

export default TestConnectDialog;
```

Comment: Hey Tammy, you are passing `isopen` that must be `isOpen`. Which is you getting from parent component, As you already extracted that in `isOpen` property, you  can directly pass `isOpen`.

Answer (score 0):

In the homepage component why is isOpen destructured from the prop and initialised in state. You have to use one, using both is confusing, you are working with that on the state but passing the one from the prop

Comment: Hi @forgha thank you for your time. It will be helpful if you suggest me some code change.

Comment: where you pass 'isOpen' in the testConnectDialog, you could pass isOpen from the prop instead of using that from the state

Comment: SO remove the isOpen in the state

Comment: Use that which comes from the prop, if it doesn't work then maybe where it is coming from is the problem